# Rails: I would like to apply a totally custom search to activerecord - is Rails fast enough?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

We have been given search ranking criteria that a simple database search cannot solve.  On the otehr hand, there are fewer than 10,000 to 100,000 records.  Each record only has a few fields.  These are weighted against the search terms in a way that isn't an exact match, but rather weights depending on the number of matches.

Would it be possible to treat these as objects and manually iterate over all of them, or would this be prohibitive?  We only expect a few concurrent users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating over Rails records can be fast or slow, depending on your object size ([I've written about this before](http://gavinmiller.io/2013/active-records-dirty-little-secret/)). Ultimately this is not what ActiveRecord/Rails ought to be used for.

What you're better off using is a search engine. It's what they're designed for. I've had excellent experience with [WebSolr](https://websolr.com/) and I've heard very good things about [Elasticsearch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elasticsearch).

Effectively you can define your criteria for what data you're looking to index, and how it's weighted, and then use the search engine to retrieve the results. Across a data set roughly your size, I saw Rails queries take 3-4 seconds vs < 200ms with WebSolr.

Comment: I used ElasticSearch, Solr, and Lucene. It's necessary to use one for complicated queries over multiple fields with lots of records. ActiveRecord simply can't compete.

Comment: @Dbz ElasticSearch & Solr are both wrappers around Lucence.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you!  @Gavin - how does ElasticSearch work?  You upload your whole database to it, don't you?  This is way out of left field but if rails is a bit slow, could we load the objects (as an array of structs) into a C++ program and just do the algorithm manually?  Or would this be a bad idea given the lack of an obvious rails / activerecord interface?  I ask because elastic might not support the exact algorithm out of the box. (But it is easy to code in a for loop.)

Comment: @RDoe you setup indexing for your Models which can handle weighted indexing fairly well. Without seeing your algorithm it would be tough to comment on whether WebSolr can handle it or not. Have a read through the sunspot docs here: https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot which is what I used as an indexing DSL for WebSolr.

Answer (score 0):

Well, 10K records can be easily iterated and compared by some custom matcher even on a free Heroku instance. 100K will be a bit more time consuming, but on a reasonably fat server it should be ok for just a few users.